# The threat of highwaymen had also lost some of the lurid colour of her imagination

Tags: grammar

The sentence is:

> The threat of highwaymen had also lost some of the lurid colour of her imagination.

This is from a book called *The Marriage Season* by Jane Dunn.
What does this sentence mean and how does it make sense grammatically?
What is the verb subject and object?

Comment: She once imagined that it was exciting to think about how scary robbers were. *Threat* is your subject.

Comment: It's literature, so?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Highwayman_(poem)

Comment: https://poets.org/poem/highwayman

Comment: SOV: *The threat lost color.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the meaning of *lurid*:

> Cambridge
> *lurid*:
> Shocking
> (especially of a description) shocking because involving violence, sex, or immoral activity

She originally imagined that an encounter with highwaymen would be lurid in this sense; that it would involve exciting violent, immoral and even sexual threat; her original ideas were somewhat romantic.

But now, she realises that an encounter would be comparatively dull and sordid; that it would probably merely be a demand for money or valuables from rather ordinary robbers who wanted to get away as quickly as possible.

Hence we may understand the usage as:

The {now imagined} threat {to her} of highwaymen had also lost some of the lurid colour of her {original} imagination {of them}.